# Entity Framework Fluent Mapping Optional One-To-One

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, fluent

I need to set up a relationship that is currently a one-to-many:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public int? BarId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public FooMap()
{
    HasKey(e => e.FooId);
    Property(e => e.FooId.IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(e => e.BarId).IsOptional();
    ...
    HasOptional(e => e.Bar).WithMany(Foos).HasForeignKey(e => e.BarId);
}

public BarMap()
{
    HasKey(e => e.BarId);
    Property(e => e.BarId.IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    ...
    HasMany(e => e.Foos).WithOptional(e => e.Bar).HasForeignKey(e => e.BarId);
}
```

However, in reality, Bar can only be assigned to a single Foo. Is it possible to set this up so I have a single Foo navigation property in Bar rather than a collection of Foos? I still want my tables to render:

```
Foos
- FooId
- BarId (null)
- ...

Bars
- BarId
- ...
```

and I want my classes to be:

```
Foo
- FooId
- BarId
- ...
- Bar

Bar
- BarId
- ...
- Foo
```

I've been fiddling around with WithOptionalDependant and WithOptionalPrincipal, but can't find the correct combination. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to model an optional 1 : 1 association is (in `FooMap`)

```
HasOptional(f => f.Bar).WithRequired(b => b.Foo);
```

But it does not produce the model you want. It does not need `Foo.BarId`, because `Bar.BarId` is both a primary key and a foreign key to `Foo.FooId`.

If you'd have `Foo.BarId` it should have a unique constraint to ensure that it is only used once in a FK association. So you might as well use the already available unique field, the primary key.

**EDIT**

It was not clear to me that you wanted both sides of the association to be optional. You can achieve that by (in `BarMap`):

```
HasOptional(b => b.Foo).WithOptionalPrincipal(f => f.Bar)
                       .Map(m => m.MapKey("BarId"));
```

This brings you the data model you showed in your post.

Comment: Unfortunately, Foo is not required to have a Bar and, inversely, Bar is not required to have a Foo so I don't think this will work.

Comment: Almost there! Unfortunately I cannot have a property BarId on my Foo class because it conflicts with the mapped key. It's not entirely necessary to have, but it would be nice. I have always mapped the key as well as the referenced class in the past using the HasForeignKey() method which is not available in WithOptionalPrincipal().

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported. Never really noticed that. I can't think of any reason why this should not be supported as it is in one-to-many. Is it a show stopper?

Comment: Nope, not a showstopper. I'll just have to navigate one more level in my select LINQ statements. My only concern is with lazy loading. If I've already loaded Foo, I'd hate to have to lazy load Bar just to get BarId from a Foo object. Most of the time I'm selecting out a model class from the datacontext that is already flattened the way I want so it's probably not a real issue. But it just seems weird that having the FK property is supported in one-to-manys but not one-to-ones.