# One or Zero to One Entity Framework Code First FluentApi

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

1. I need to create fluentapi one or zero to one reference and have navigation properties on both of entities.
2. EntityTwo should contain simple proerty to store foreign key (EntityOneId)

   ```
   public class EntityOne
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public EntityTwo EntityTwo { get; set; }
   }

   public class EntityTwo
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int EntityOneId { get; set; }
       public EntityOne EntityOne { get; set; }
   }

   public class MyDbContext : DbContext
   {
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
           //some code trimmed

           modelBuilder.Entity<EntityOne>()
               .HasOptional(entity => entity.EntityTwo)
               .WithRequired();

           modelBuilder.Entity<EntityTwo>()
               .HasRequired(entity => entity.EntityOne)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.EntityOneId)
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
       }
   }
   ```

more complex scenario:

```
public class EntityOne
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public EntityTwo EntityTwo { get; set; }
}

public class EntityThree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public EntityTwo EntityTwo { get; set; }
}

public class EntityTwo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int EntityOneId { get; set; }

    public EntityOne EntityOne { get; set; }

    public int EntityThreeId { get; set; }

    public EntityThree EntityThree { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //some code trimmed

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityOne>()
            .HasOptional(entity => entity.EntityTwo)
            .WithRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityThree>()
            .HasOptional(entity => entity.EntityTwo)
            .WithRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityTwo>()
            .HasRequired(entity => entity.EntityOne)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.EntityOneId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityTwo>()
            .HasRequired(entity => entity.EntityThree)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.EntityThreeId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791961/entity-framework-fluent-mapping-optional-one-to-one). Or am I wrong?

Comment: For clarity, you may use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182785/1941942

Answer (score 14):

In one-to-one relation one end must be **principal** and second end must be **dependent**. Principal end is the one which will be inserted first and which can exist without the dependent one. Dependent end is the one which must be inserted after the principal because it has foreign key to the principal. When configuring one-to-one relationships, Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent also be the foreign key.  The proper way to achieve what you want could be this, but is using Data Annotations:

```
public class EntityOne
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual EntityTwo EntityTwo { get; set; }
}

 public class EntityTwo
 {
   [Key, ForeignKey("EntityOne")]
   public int EntityOneId { get; set; }
   public virtual EntityOne EntityOne { get; set; }
}
```

I suggest you check this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s07.html), you can find there more info about how work the one-to-one relationships in EF Code First.

### Update:

I am afraid that what you want is not possible.You can't create a one-to-one relation with a FK that is not declared as a PK. If you want to have each Entities with their own `Id` an configure an one-to-one relationship between that two entities, then delete the FK property in the `EntityTwo`.

My recomendation is map that relationship using Fluent Api as I show below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityTwo>()
        .HasRequired(et => et.EntityOne)
        .WithOptional(eo=>eo.EntityTwo);
}
```

Or you can just add the `Required` attribute over the navigation property that is principal, for example:

```
public class EntityTwo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  // public int EntityOneId { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public EntityOne EntityOne { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This example is working, however it not fits my expections. I expect EntityTwo have its own Id, with links to other entities (each link is unique)

Comment: Hello @OlegGochachko. I have updated my answer some time ago. Did you try with that configuration?

Comment: "You can't create a one-to-one relation with a FK that is not declared as a PK."
By SQL, it should be enough that the FK is one of the candidate keys.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've come up with to handle this is, which is admittedly somewhat ugly, is creating a collection and a helper property to represent the one/zero side. Data annotations included for clarity.

```cs
public class EntityOne
{
    [Key]
    public int EntityOneId { get; set; }

    public EntityTwo EntityTwo => EntityTwoNavigation?.FirstOrDefault();
    public ICollection<EntityTwo> EntityTwoNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class EntityTwo
{
    [Key]
    public int EntityTwoId { get; set; }
    public int EntityOneId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityOneId")]
    public EntityOne EntityOne { get; set; }
}
```