# FluentAPI setup for one-to-zero-or-one without MapKey

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to setup a one to zero-or-one relationship, I thought I had it worked out, but I was wrong as I testing further.  I clearly do not understand FluentAPI too well, but I also see that many have had the same or similar issue I am experiencing

Here are my Classes:

```
public class BaseLogObject
{
    public BaseLogObject()
    {
        Oid = Guid.NewGuid();
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid Oid { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class AccessLog : BaseLogObject
{
    public virtual ErrorLog ErrorLog { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorLog : BaseLogObject
{
    //Hoping to keep this property, but .MapKey give "Unique" error
    [Display(Name = "Access Log")]
    public virtual Guid? AccessLogID { get; set; }

    public virtual AccessLog AccessLog { get; set; }
}
```

FluentAPI setup:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ErrorLog>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.AccessLog)
        .WithOptionalDependent(x => x.ErrorLog)
        .Map(a => a.MapKey("AccessLogID"));

    //Thought this worked, but AccessLogID became the PrimaryKey
    //modelBuilder.Entity<ErrorLog>().HasKey(x => x.AccessLogID);
    //modelBuilder.Entity<ErrorLog>().HasRequired(x => x.AccessLog);

    //This creates a new column in SQL (AccessLog_Oid)
    //modelBuilder.Entity<AccessLog>()
    //  .HasOptional(pi => pi.ErrorLog)
    //  .WithOptionalDependent(x => x.AccessLog);

    //Tried reversing the relationship, no go
    //modelBuilder.Entity<AccessLog>()
    //  .HasOptional(x => x.ErrorLog)
    //  .WithRequired(x => x.AccessLog);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

> AccessLogID: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'AccessLogID' is already defined.

I understand that `AccessLogID` is a duplicate, but was hoping that I could leave it in my `ErrorLog` model so I can reference it throughout the application (techincally, I am saving the Guid in a Session and logging Errors/Exceptions to it as needed, I am trying to avoid storing the entire Object, just the Guid).

Answer (score 1):

Asked many times out here. It is not a well supported relationship. You either have to share a primary key, or set it up as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ErrorLog>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.AccessLog)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.AccessLogID);
```

Similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701378/implementing-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship-in-ef-code-first-by-fluent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499126/one-or-zero-to-one-entity-framework-code-first-fluentapi).

Comment: I've set this up, it the intention to change `public virtual ErrorLog ErrorLog { get; set; }` to `public virtual List<ErrorLog> ErrorLogs { get; set; }`?  (on the `AccessLog` class)

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. The `WithMany()` is just a mechanism(hack) for EF to configure a working solution.

Comment: I just noticed that the `AccessLog` table has `ErrorLog_Oid` in it when I have `public virtual ErrorLog ErrorLog { get; set; }`.  Is there something I need to configure with `.Entity<AccessLog>` or does AccessLog need to have a ForeignKey for the ErrorLog property?

Comment: Correct. Your other option is to make AccessLogId both a PK and a FK to ErrorLog. Your inheritance structure would interfere with that currently.

Comment: I always thought the inheritance of `BaseLogObject` would get in the way of something, am I able to `override` the Oid and put Annotations on it? Thank you for all your help btw.

Comment: I'm not sure. The only inheritance I've used is TPH.